# Unable to access .auc files inside User Profile Disk VHDXs through Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, dynamics-ax-2012

Looking for ways to delete .auc files related to each user which are stored inside the .vhdx files on a network shared folder. 
Have tried with `Get-childItem -path "Shared folder" -Include *.auc -recurse | Remove-item -force`
But it is not doing anything, the files are still in there. ( Users were not connected at the time of testing, so vhdx were free to access manually using file explorer)

Comment: `Get-childItem -path "Shared folder" -Include *.auc -recurse` - does running this on it's own give you a list of the expected .auc files?

Comment: no, had to mount those vhds first one by one and then access the files using powershell